# FOREIGN KEY constraint failed in Web2py

Tags: python, web2py

I've below two tables in tables.py -

```
db.define_table('spr_details',
Field('SPR_name', 'string', unique=True, notnull=True),
Field('Object_location',notnull=True),
Field('NSK_System',notnull=True,),
primarykey = ['SPR_name'],migrate=True)

db.define_table('my_master_table',
Field('Test_id',notnull=True),
Field('Test_suite',notnull=True),
Field('Test_category',notnull=True),
Field('Test_unit',notnull=True),
Field('Test_case',notnull=True),
Field ('Applicability', db.spr_details,'string'),migrate=True)
```

I inserted one row in spr_details table. Now when I am inserting record in my_master table, I am selecting previously inserted value from Applicability drop-down column. But on submitting it, I am getting

> FOREIGN KEY constraint failed error.

below is the stack trace -

[Stack trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TiGY.png)

```
Traceback

 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pandeyar\Downloads\web2py_src\web2py\gluon\restricted.py", line 219, in restricted
    exec(ccode, environment)
  File "C:/Users/pandeyar/Downloads/web2py_src/web2py/applications/JDBC_E2E/controllers/default.py", line 183, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\pandeyar\Downloads\web2py_src\web2py\gluon\globals.py", line 419, in <lambda>
    self._caller = lambda f: f()
  File "C:/Users/pandeyar/Downloads/web2py_src/web2py/applications/JDBC_E2E/controllers/default.py", line 99, in admin
    user_signature=False,
  File "C:\Users\pandeyar\Downloads\web2py_src\web2py\gluon\sqlhtml.py", line 3338, in smartgrid
    user_signature=user_signature, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\pandeyar\Downloads\web2py_src\web2py\gluon\sqlhtml.py", line 2534, in grid
    onsuccess=oncreate)
  File "C:\Users\pandeyar\Downloads\web2py_src\web2py\gluon\html.py", line 2300, in process
    self.validate(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\pandeyar\Downloads\web2py_src\web2py\gluon\html.py", line 2238, in validate
    if self.accepts(**kwargs):
  File "C:\Users\pandeyar\Downloads\web2py_src\web2py\gluon\sqlhtml.py", line 1965, in accepts
    self.vars.id = self.table.insert(**fields)
  File "C:\Users\pandeyar\Downloads\web2py_src\web2py\gluon\packages\dal\pydal\objects.py", line 753, in insert
    ret = self._db._adapter.insert(self, row.op_values())
  File "C:\Users\pandeyar\Downloads\web2py_src\web2py\gluon\packages\dal\pydal\adapters\base.py", line 486, in insert
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\pandeyar\Downloads\web2py_src\web2py\gluon\packages\dal\pydal\adapters\base.py", line 481, in insert
    self.execute(query)
  File "C:\Users\pandeyar\Downloads\web2py_src\web2py\gluon\packages\dal\pydal\adapters\__init__.py", line 67, in wrap
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\pandeyar\Downloads\web2py_src\web2py\gluon\packages\dal\pydal\adapters\base.py", line 412, in execute
    rv = self.cursor.execute(command, *args[1:], **kwargs)
sqlite3.IntegrityError: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
```

Any help would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to the documentation on [keyed tables](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#Legacy-databases-and-keyed-tables) (i.e., tables whose primary key is not the default auto-incrementing integer ID field), as `spr_details` is such a table.

Note, there are two problems with your reference field definition:

```
    Field('Applicability', db.spr_details, 'string')
```

First, as noted in the documentation, when referencing a keyed table, the format for the `type` argument to `Field()` must be `'reference tablename.fieldname'`, not `db.tablename`. Second, you do not separately specify the type of a reference field (i.e., you should not pass `'string'` as the third argument to `Field()`, as the third argument is the `length` argument, not the `type` -- the `type` is inferred based on the type of the referenced field). So, the field definition should be:

```
    Field('Applicability', 'reference spr_details.SPR_name')
```

Note, with your current incorrect definition of the `Applicability` field, the field becomes an integer field (as it expects to store a reference to an integer ID field in the foreign table). If you attempt to insert an integer, you will get a foreign key constraint failure error, and if you attempt to insert a string, you will get an error about inserting a string where an `int` is expected. You should not get any errors if you use the correct field definition as shown above and insert string values that match values that exist in the `db.spr_details.SPR_name` field.

Also note that web2py assumes keyed tables will be used together (i.e., both the referenced and the referencing table will be keyed). So, for example, if you use `SQLFORM` with `my_master_table`, by default it will assume that because `my_master_table` is not keyed, neither is the `spr_details` table that it references. It will therefore attempt to convert the value of `SPR_details` to an integer ID (which results in a conversion to `0`, which leads to a foreign key constraint error). To work around this, you should handle the database inserts and updates manually -- for example:

```
form = SQLFORM(db.my_master_table).process(dbio=False)
if form.accepted:
    db.my_master_table.insert(**form.vars)
```

Above, setting `dbio=False` prevents `SQLFORM` from doing the insert itself (which will result in an error). Instead, the insert is done explicitly using the values in `form.vars`.

Comment: Hi Anthony, Thanks for your reply.
Before posting I had tried almost all the possibilities but no luck. I even had tried your solution also but even then same error is coming. Looks like as mentioned in the document, it is not supported for all DBs except DB2 and MySQL. Very strange but looks like this basic feature of database is not present as of now. 
So with this I'll have to go with id only. Please let me know if you can think of any workaround or suggestion. Thanks for helping me out here.

Comment: Using the above code with SQLite definitely works. If you are still encountering errors, I suggest you show the exact code you are using to make inserts. Also, the list of supported databases says DB2, MS-SQL, Ingres, and Informix, though I don't think that is up-to-date -- keyed tables probably work with most supported RDBMSes. In any case, the purpose of the keyed table functionality is to support legacy database schemas where you don't have a choice -- if you are creating a new database from scratch, it is probably best to stick with the auto-incrementing ID primary key.

Comment: table structure is as below -

`db.define_table('spr_details',
    Field('SPR_name', 'string', unique=True, notnull=True),
    Field('Object_location',notnull=True),
    Field('NSK_System',notnull=True,),
    primarykey = ['SPR_name'],migrate=True)`  
 

`db.define_table('my_master_table',
    Field('Test_id',notnull=True),
    Field('Test_suite',notnull=True),
    Field('Test_category',notnull=True),
    Field('Test_unit',notnull=True),
    Field('Test_case',notnull=True),
    Field('Applicability', 'reference spr_details.SPR_name'),migrate=True)`

Comment: Then I inserted a row in `spr_details` table. This row has `L36^ASM` as value for `Spr Name` column.
Now when I am trying to add records for `my_master_table`, `L36^ASM` is coming in Applicability column dropdown.
After selecting this value I am clicking on submit. then `FOREIGN KEY constraint failed` comes
@Anthony

Comment: I meant you should update the question, not put additional information in the comments. Also, it is important to show all of your code -- presumably you are using `SQLFORM`, but you do not show it in your code. I have updated the answer assuming you are using `SQLFORM`. Note, I would still recommend sticking with the default ID field in `spr_details` (you can still include the `SPR_name` field in addition -- just don't use it as the primary key).

Comment: thanks for your detailed reply. I'll try this and let you know.

Comment: Hi @Anothony, I could solve the problem just by adding a primary key in `my_master_table`. All code remains same. Thanks for all your help. For web2py, whichever thread I open, I see only you answering the question. Thanks for making our life easy.. :)